# Фрагментация таблиц - почему команда Alter table move не смещает HWM?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Ситуация следующая, есть рабочая БД с несколькими табличными пространствами (ТП). Необходимо сместить HWM на одной из них.

Для тестов создаю тестовое ТП, помещаю в нее таблицу и заполняю данными. Проверяю заполненное пространство, удаляю данные, выполняю команду `Alter table ... move`. Убеждаюсь, что ТП освободилось и HWM сместилось.

Но на рабочем ТП команда `Alter table ... move`, не смещает HWM.

Что может запрещать фрагментацию <sub>(Прим.ред.: дефрагментацию)</sub> таблицы?

---

Доп. инф.: Смещение HWM характеризуется освобождением сегментов таблицы, поэтому использую view `user_segments`, где вижу количество блоков, занимаемые таблицей.

Comment: скорее всего вам придется переместить __все__ объекты из вашего рабочего tablespace, для того чтобы уменьшить его... PS уточните вопрос - вы пытаетесь урезать HWM для таблицы или для "tablespace"?

Comment: Alter table. пытаюсь урезать hwm сегмента таблицы.

Comment: А как смотрите HWM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Смещение HWM характеризуется освобождением сегментов таблицы, поэтому использую view user_segments, где вижу количество блоков, занимаемые таблицей.

Не совсем так. Освобождением не сегментов, a экстентов таблицы.
HWM это последний по порядку блок в одном из экстентов сегмента таблицы, который уже когда-то содержал данные. Все последующиe за ним блоки, не отформатированы и никогда ещё не использовались (*unused blocks*). Представление `user_segments` информацию о них не содержит.

Расмотрим сценарий из вопроса на примере. Для определения заполняемости, HWM и фрагментации сегмента используется пакет [`DBMS_SPACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SPACE.html#GUID-9C886E0A-7A44-4D9B-A255-AF16FDD47A54) (рекомендуемый).

Создадим таблицу и заполним её данными:

```sql
create table t1 (id number, memo varchar2 (4000)) segment creation immediate; 

insert into t1
    select level id, lpad ('A', 2000, 'A') memo from dual connect by level<=10e3;
commit;

select segment_type, segment_subtype, blocks, extents, next_extent
from user_segments 
where segment_name = upper ('t1')
/
SEGMENT_TYPE       SEGMENT_SU     BLOCKS    EXTENTS NEXT_EXTENT
------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
TABLE              ASSM             3456         42     1048576

var rc refcursor
set autoprint on
exec :rc := showSpaceUsage ('T1')

Blocks% (0-25) Blocks% (25-50) Blocks% (50-75) Blocks% (75-100) Full Blocks
-------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------- -----------
             0               0               1               14        3333

exec :rc := showUnusedSpace ('T1')

Total Blocks Unused Blocks        HWM
------------ ------------- ----------
        3456             0       3456
```

Всё хорошо, сегмент не фрагментирован, только 15 незаполненых блоков. Удалим каждую вторую запись:

```sql
delete from t1 where id = case mod (id, 2) when 0 then id end;
commit; 

Blocks% (0-25) Blocks% (25-50) Blocks% (50-75) Blocks% (75-100) Full Blocks
-------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------- -----------
             0            1667            1666               15           0

Total Blocks Unused Blocks        HWM
------------ ------------- ----------
        3456             0       3456
```

Теперь сегмент сильно фрагментирован и желательна его реорганизация (синоним: дефрагментация):

```sql
alter table t1 move;

Blocks% (0-25) Blocks% (25-50) Blocks% (50-75) Blocks% (75-100) Full Blocks
-------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------- -----------
             0               0               0                0        1667

Total Blocks Unused Blocks        HWM
------------ ------------- ----------
        1792            89       1703
```

Таблица выглядит теперь как нельзя лучше, большая часть неиспользуемых экстентов возвращена обратно (освобождена).

Что же могло помешать тому же случится с таблицей в продуктивной БД? С точностью можно ответить, если видеть все данные, как показано выше. Но одно предположение можно сделать, которое с вероятностью ~90% верно. Продуктивная БД находится под нагрузкой, доля вставок обычно значительно выше удалений, как результат - сегмент может заполнится.

Выполнив теже действия ещё раз, только со вставкой до команды `alter table ...`, можно увидеть, что острой нужды в реорганизации больше не было, и как результат - ни один экстент не был освобождён. Это и воспринял ТС как невозможность дефрагментации таблицы:

```sql
insert into t1
    select level id, lpad ('A', 2000, 'A') memo from dual connect by level<=5000; 
commit; 
 
Blocks% (0-25) Blocks% (25-50) Blocks% (50-75) Blocks% (75-100) Full Blocks
-------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------- -----------
             2              28              29               32        3303

Total Blocks Unused Blocks        HWM
------------ ------------- ----------
        3456             0       3456

alter table t1 move;

Blocks% (0-25) Blocks% (25-50) Blocks% (50-75) Blocks% (75-100) Full Blocks
-------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------- -----------
             0               0               0                0        3334

Total Blocks Unused Blocks        HWM
------------ ------------- ----------
        3456            60       3396
```